# ¿como puedo borrar este mensaje en la terminal gitbash?

Tags: git, npm, git-bash, mingw

una vez tratando de configurar el autor y correo de un repositorio en la terminal, al cometer el error de dar enter en lugar de (yes) me aparece una advertencia en la terminal.

npm WARN config init.author.email Use `--init-author-email` instead.
npm WARN config init.author.name Use `--init-author-name` instead.

Desde entonces cada vez que quiero hacer algo en la terminal usando git, me aparece ese mensaje y quiero borrarlo. Cabe aclarar que después de dos intentos, si pude configurar el nombre y el correo del autor. Pero en cada enter que doy a la terminal me sigue apareciendo ese mensaje, como si el proceso quedara inconcluso.

[image: Error de npm warn config author]

Answer (score 0):

En tu archivo `.npmrc`, localizado en el directorio home del usuario, cambia las claves `init.author.email` por `init-author-email`, y `init.author.name` por `init-author-name`.